# Is there an equivalent to \ddot for MnSymbol?

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility, accents

In my bibtex file (in Jabref) I have several authors that require an umlaut. I was using \ddot which was doing the trick. Unfortunately I've needed to load some other symbols from MnSymbol that requires amsmath as well. As a result I can no longer use \ddot. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can give my authors back their umlaut?

I get the following error message when I use \ddot:
`! Package amsmath Error: \ddot allowed only in math mode.`

Comment: Why don't you just use `\"` for umlauts (as in `G\"odel`)?

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. I'd been using the wrong quote marks. It now works brilliantly.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is OK with you, I will turn my comment into an aswer so you can consider accepting it.

Comment: Of course that would be fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\"` for umlauts in the .bib file:

```
@article{aksin,
  author      = {Aks{\i}n, {\"O}zge and T{\"u}rkmen, Hayati and Artok, Levent and
                 {\k{C}}etinkaya, Bekir and Ni, Chaoying and B{\"u}y{\"u}kg{\"u}ng{\"o}r, Orhan
                 and {\"O}zkal, Erhan},
  title       = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated
                 Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions},
  journal     = jomch,
  volume      = {691},
  number      = {13},
  year        = {2006},
  pages       = {3027--3036}
}
```